# customising behaviour of Jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using Jquery validate to provide feedback to a user and provide them updates on the validity of the details they enter in the form.  But I am having trouble customising the behaviour Jquery validate creates.

I have a simple form like this:

```
<form id="form1">
<label for="input1" />
<input name="input1" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When the user enters invalid information I want Jquery validate to output something like this:

```
<form id="form1">
<label for="input1" />
<input name="input1" class="error"/><span class="errorIcon">Error</span>
<p class="errorText">Error message</p>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When the user fills out the field with valid information I want Jquery validate to output:

```
<form id="form1">
<label for="input1" />
<input name="input1" /><span class="successIcon">Success</span>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I have set up the required rules and custom validation messages so they fire fine but I am having trouble getting the behaviour described above.

I have this currently:

```
$('#form1').validate({
 showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
 if (errorList < 1 ) {
   $('span.errorIcon').remove();
   $('p.errorText').remove();
   $('input.error').removeClass('error');
   $('select.error').removeClass('error');
   return;
 }
 $.each(errorList, function(index, error) {
   if ($(error.element).siblings('.errorText').length === 0 && $(error.element).siblings('.errorIcon').length === 0)  {
     $(error.element).next('p.errorText').remove();
     $(error.element).addClass('error');
     $(error.element).after(
       $('<p/>')
  .addClass('errorText')
  .append(error.message)
  );
   $(error.element).after(
       $('<span>There is an issue with this field</span>')
  .addClass('errorIcon')
   );
}
});
},
//rules and messages defined here
);
```

So the above doesn't achieve what I want need currently and it also feels like I might be over complicating this issue.  I am fairly inexperienced with javascript and Jquery.  Any guidance in getting this sorted would be appreciated.

Cheers

EDIT:

Here is a link to a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WJ9Vt/4/ with the sample form.

Answer (score 0):

Could also post you css file, or do a jsfiddle on it ? Because you errorIcon is probably not shown because `<span>` will not display something as long as it has no content or you set `display:block;` and a special `height` and `width`.

Comment: The span has content in it, I have amend my question to reflect this, sorry for any confusion.

Comment: okay no problem, but could you do a jsfiddle for that ? would like to help you but without that its difficult.

Comment: I included a link to a jsfiddle in my original post, I will keep updating it as I make progress on this as well.  Thanks.